# Knockout JS clear function ko.observable

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to remove/clear a field of its bindings.

```
self.Selected = ko.observable();

"Selected": {
    "ID": 5,
    "Name": "22",
    "Active": true,
    "Temp": "2013-01-28T18:14:48.340Z"
  }
```

self.Selected.remove() --- > error: has no method 'remove'

self.Selected.removeAll();  --> Cannot call method 'removeAll' of undefined

self.Selected.cleanNode()--- > error: has no method 'cleanNode'

http://jsfiddle.net/yvTFN/24/    :   so you can see a working example

After you EDIT a name, the  self.update = function will do work, then should clear the property Selected, otherwise, if you click update again (no value), the value will update with empty string.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just set the value of `Selected` to `null`:

```
self.Selected(null);
```

**Edit:** Your jsfiddle is using `ko.removeNode` which does not what you want.

For a working version see: http://jsfiddle.net/yvTFN/26/

Answer (score 1):

```
self.Selected.clearBindings = function __clearSelection__() {
    self.Selected = new ko.observable(self.Selected());
    self.Selected.clearBindings = __clearSelection__;
}
```

This approach may do what you need, depending on what it is you really need...  There are some caveats

- I don't know the internals of KnockoutJS
- There will probably be memory leaks in some browsers (IE<9)
- If this is a long-running page, and this method called many times, you may have unexpected results.